# @State is not working on iPad Swift Playgrounds

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui, playgrounds

I'm trying to use SwiftUI on my iPad with Swift Playgrounds. The view below renders fine initially, but unfortunately the view does not update when `@State` changes, like it does on my Mac. In the little sidebar I can see the closure does get executed though...

I'm using the newest non-beta version of everything.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tapCount = 0

    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap count: \(tapCount)") {
            tapCount += 1
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677361. `Enable Results` should be turned off.